# Executing code after activity is displayed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I am trying to run some scripts after the activity is displayed. I am loading some images from the web and displaying them on the activity dynamically. I am running multiple runnables and each runnable calls an `Asynctask` (reading image and assigning to `ImageView`, Image Views are created in the `onCreate` function) but the activity is displayed only after all runnables asynctasks complete.

I hope you can help me achieve this. What I am looking for is to display the activity and then load and show images one after the other.

```java
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (!hasFocus)
        return;
    Handler h = new Handler();
    Runnable[] r;
    int i = 0;
    r = new Runnable[files.length];
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        r[i] = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.RootView);

                Log.v("ASYNC", "Starting Call " + j);
                // new BitmapWorkerTask().execute(img, i);
                new BitmapWorkerTask(img, j).execute();
                vg.invalidate();
            }
        };
        h.post(r[i]);
        Log.v("ASYNC", "Posted " + i);
    }
    return;
};
```

Comment: How many images are there? I'd probably be inclined to spawn a single AsyncTask to retrieve images one after the other.

Comment: Using a single AsyncTask, you'd be able to update the UI with the just downloaded image using publishProgress()

Answer (score 0):

`onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` is not an `Activity` lifecycle method. You should be firing off your tasks in `onCreate` instead. If it takes a long time to load, then you can show a progress spinner of some sort.